# How to check the pdf file is converted from other file types

Tags: android, pdf

I wanna know is the pdf file converted from other file types. Is there any possible ways to find this. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: A project requirement.

Comment: Sure, but do you know why it is a requirement? Does knowing this help your project somehow? There might be a better way to accomplish the underlying requirement, but you would have to give extra context to the requirement.

Comment: The requirement is to do POC (Proof of Concept) to know the actually generated from image conversion or written in pdf.

Answer (score 2):

In general no, you could not determine that.

The closest you would find is the **Producer** entry of the **Document Information Dictionary**, but this tells your application, not the file type, so you would have to assume a PDF from Word was a DOCX for example.

> Producer : (Optional; deprecated in PDF 2.0) If the document was
>   converted to PDF from another format, the name of the PDF processor
>   that converted it to PDF. NOTE 7 The pdf:Producer entry in the
>   document’s metadata stream can be used to represent the tool that
>   saved the document as a PDF.

You can disregard the deprecated part for the next decade... essentially every PDF has this entry.